# Reference a caller (UIViewController) view inside a method when it's called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, extension-methods

I'm extending the UIView to create a custom view that will be used inside my all UIViewControllers in the app, this is created like:

```
extension UIView {

class func customBar() -> UIView {
    let barview = UIView()
    barView.backgroundColor = .red
    barView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

}
```

The caller of this method is always a UIViewController, I want to reference the caller ViewController's view's dimensions to add a constraints for the bar, this way it will always show at the same location. So I tried this:

```
class func customBar() -> UIView {
    let barview = UIView()
    barView.backgroundColor = .red
    barView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    barView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: barView.superView!.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    barView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: barView.superView!.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    barView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: barView.superView!.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    barView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}
```

But this will cause a crash because when I call this function, it's not yet added to the viewController's view, thus, the superView is `nil`. Here's how I call it inside of `viewDidLoad()`

```
let customBar = UIView.customBar()
self.view.addSubview(customBar)
```

Please, if you have any question, ask me instead of downvoting.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest way be to pass in the view that you want the bar attached to?  Or, if it wasn't a class method, you could have an interface such as `self.view.addCustomBar()`.

Answer (score 0):

> But this will cause a crash because when I call this function, it's not yet added to the viewController's view, thus, the superView is nil.

Since the constraint-adding code must not run until the view has a superview, put it in the view's `didMoveToSuperview`.

Comment: Now should I call `didMoveToSuperview` inside of the viewController that will add the barView and call the barView method inside of `didMoveToSuperview`?

Comment: You don't call it. It is called when you have a superview, so that is the moment when you want to set up the constraints.

Comment: I mean, I don't know where to add the view as a subView of the UIViewController now.

Comment: Why not do it where you were doing it? That was never the problem.